# converting div containing image, to canvas gives a black and white image

Tags: html2canvas

I wanted an image to be uploaded to a div inside a page and convert the whole div to an image..,

The resulting images what I got is attested below.., its converting that color image to a b/w image.., and some saturation too..

The original image after appending to a div

[image]

After converting div to image(canvas)

[image]

I wanted an image to be uploaded to a div inside a page and convert the whole div to an image..,

Comment: Create a plunk of your code..there is no much information for some one to help

Comment: its pretty much straight forward.., the image appended is a child of div element.., and the div is given to html2canvas function..,